# Como resolver problema de ids no jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho dois formulários quase iguais, um para pessoa física e outro para pessoa jurídica e estes formulários estão escondidos e aparecem conforme o resultado de um `jQuery().change` que determina se é o formulário para pessoa física ou pessoa jurídica a ser usado.

Em ambos os formulários estou chamando `ids` idênticos aonde no `pfisica` tem `#estado` e `#cidade` e no `pjuridica` também, preciso das mesmas informações.

Uma função **jQuery().change** no select `#estado` chama a função `buscar_cidades()` que captura o id do estado selecionado e busca no banco de dados com Ajax.

Como os 2 forms carregam na mesma página e aparecem conforme a escolha entre `PF` ou `PJ`, como vou resolver este problema dos `ids` sabendo que ids duplicados conflitam no `jQuery`?

Uma solução seria criar duas páginas mas não queria fazer isso. Outra solução seria trocar os ids e duplicar a função buscar_cidades e trocar o nome da função que chamaria os ids do outro form mas acho que isso mais `POG` que outra coisa.

Como resolver?

***[Website em questão](http://encomenda.axitech.com.br/sys/cadastro)***

Comment: Em vez de identificar por Id, atribua uma classe comum (mesmo nome) a ambos os componentes, e selecione pelo nome da classe em vez de selecionar pelo Id.

Comment: ^^^^isto, o problema de IDs se resolve com classes. [ps] se publicar um resumo do seu código aqui dá uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, ao terminar a pergunta, eu pensei em `class`. Vou testar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tem dois selects no mesmo formulário a minha sugestão é:

```
$('#fpf select').on('change', buscar_cidades);
```

Dentro da função `buscar_cidades()` o `this` vai apontar para o select mudado. Assim pode obter:

```
this.id // o id do select mudado
this.value // o valor selecionado no select que foi mudado
```

Answer (score 3):

Em vez de identificar os campos por Id, atribua uma classe comum (mesmo nome) a ambos os componentes, e selecione pelo nome da classe em vez de selecionar pelo Id.

Por exemplo:

```
$( ".cidade" ).change(function() {
  // ...
});
```